# Indent lines in a text file that begin with a number

Tags: sed

I am trying to indent lines in a text file that start with a number by 4 spaces.

I have tried this command and this works but how would one go about indenting lines that start with a number only.

```
sed  's/^/     /'  somefile
```

I have tried the command above but it indents everything.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a filter to select only lines that start with a digit,
write before the `s///` command:

```
sed -e '/^[0-9]/s/^/    /' somefile
```

Based on your comments, your input comes from the output of `cat -n`,
which prints the lines numbered, but the lines don't start with the number, but have space padding on the left.
If you want to indent lines start with *zero or more spaces followed by a number* then you need to adjust the filter.
This is simply a matter of inserting `*` (space and `*`):

```
sed -e '/^ *[0-9]/s/^/    /' somefile
```

Comment: this does not seem to do anything

Comment: It appears this works but not with a numbered file - the example has been posted in my original question. I have a file created with cat -n file > fileout

Comment: sed -e '/^[ 0-9]/s/^/       /' output13 = works - 1 whitespace before the 0-9

Comment: @AlexTomko it seems your requirements were incomplete: the lines start with spaces followed by digits. I updated my answer to handle that, but next time please be careful to include all requirements in your question.

Comment: @AlexTomko do you need more help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace any spaces or tab characters before a number by four spaces, like so:

```
sed 's/^[ \t]*\([0-9]\+.*\)/    \1/' file
```

And since your file is the output of `cat -n` you don't really have to check for a number, as all lines are going to begin with a number anyhow, so this might work as well:

```
sed 's/^[ \t]*\(.*\)/    \1/'
```